# How to convert XmlList to ArrayList

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have this xml file.

```
var xml:XML =   <rootNode>
            <element name="CompositeFont">
                  <attribute name="Self">
                    <data type="string"/>
                  </attribute>
                  <element name="Font">
                  </element>        
            </element>
    </rootNode>;
```

I am getting XmlList of this xml by using

```
 var elementList:XMLList = xml.children();
```

But I want these node names, example: element,attribute,element in arrayList.

```
["element","attribute","element"]
```

Please, help........
Thanks.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since XmlList directly inherits Object (opposed to IList), you will have to loop over it an add each item to a new ArrayCollection.

```
var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
for each ( var xml:XML in elementList ) {
    ac.addItem(xml);
}
```